# TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function. (In 'navigation.toggleDrawer()', 'navigation.toggleDrawer' is undefined) this error occured

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function. (In 'navigation.toggleDrawer()', 'navigation.toggleDrawer' is undefined)
I've called this function as child component in drawer navigation even though it shows error as toggle drawer could not be able access the drawer menu...If anyone can help me to fix this that would be so helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try use useNavigation

If you use functional component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
 const navigation = useNavigation();

return (
   <Button
     title="Back"
     onPress={() => {
       navigation.goBack();
     }}
   />
 );
}
```

If you use class component.

```
class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
 render() {
   // Get it from props
   const { navigation } = this.props;
 }
}

  // Wrap and export
     export default function(props) {
     const navigation = useNavigation();

    return <MyBackButton {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution that could have been the reason too.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is this error occurs because I should have added that particular component in drawer navigation module. After doing that this error has gone.